# compilation linPhone sample code

Tags: android, openssl

When I have download sample code from [this link](http://www.linphone.org/eng/download/git.html) and than try to build using ndk but i haven't download complete project and some file is missing in all folders of `submodules` folder. So from where i get all files and folder for linphone.

Comment: Have you searched the files in project directory using OS search as it might be that files are there but due to error in path set its saying unable to find files

Comment: I am use win xp so i have search that all files which is needed but there's no file.

Comment: Did you downloaded the code using git clone ? My OS is ubuntu 11.04 and I used the git clone and got all the source file. But got issues in building it. I got the issue as stated in this link

Comment: yap but there's not all library in this git clone project you have to download all externally and than include into the project. like ffmpeg etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why you are not getting the files in the submodules is because you didn't include "--recursive" in your git clone. You have to type this: "git clone git://git.linphone.org/linphone-android.git --recursive"

Comment: Hi i have download the linphone code from  http://www.linphone.org/eng/download/git.html, i tried to run this command ./prepare_sources.sh on Cygwin, it doesn't complete and ends with some error. Still i complete all the steps as mentioned in Readme file attached with example. When i build and run the code it gives me java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:com.google.android.gcm.GCMRegistrar and if i comment GCM code then same error for LinphoneActivity.java. Can you please guide with whole process, from download to build and run the code or please suggest some reference link. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think in Cygwin you also have to download other sources before you can run ./prepare_sources.sh

Comment: if you mean submodules by other sources then i have already downloaded them by using --recursive in git clone command. And if you talking about "autoconf automake libtool pkg-config" tools then afaik these tools comes with Cygwin. Please correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: i get below error while executing ./prepare_sources.sh command on Cygwin.  =================================
cd SILK_SDK_SRC_v1.0.9/SILK_SDK_SRC_ARM_v1.0.9 && /usr/bin/patch -p0 < patch_pic.diff
patching file Makefile
Hunk #1 FAILED at 26.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file Makefile.rej
Makefile:420: recipe for target `SILK_SDK_SRC_v1.0.9/SILK_SDK_SRC_ARM_v1.0.9' failed
make: *** [SILK_SDK_SRC_v1.0.9/SILK_SDK_SRC_ARM_v1.0.9] Error 1
SILK audio plugin prepare state failed.
./prepare_sources.sh: line 41: xxd: command not found
./prepare_sources.sh: line 47: xxd: command not found

Comment: Because I remembered I need to download some other tools besides cygwin to run the command. I can't exactly remember it as I haven't been doing the linphone for a period of time. By right it should be running fine if the other submodules are downloaded.

Comment: I have included "Devel" package (made it intall from Defualt) which includes automake,autoconf,aclocal, libtool (i guess similar to libtoolize), pkg-config in cygwin. Let me know if you get any clues from this.